# C# Git Command issue

Tags: c#, .net, git

I am developing an App where I need to Run Git Command from C#. I used Process to run Commands if I am passing user Name and password then Is says UserName or Password is Incorrect  but it actual working Conventional. Below is my Code:-

```
public static void PullCode(string gitCommand)
{
    string strPassword = "Password";
    ProcessStartInfo gitInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    Process gitProcess = new Process();

    gitInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    gitInfo.UserName = "UserNAme";
    gitInfo.Password = Misc.ConvertPassword(strPassword);
    gitInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    gitInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe";  //git repostory directory path
    gitInfo.Arguments = gitCommand; //git command such as "fetch orign"
    gitInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"E:\Code Demo\testrepo";  //YOUR_GIT_REPOSITORY_PATH Where you want to Copy Data
    gitInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    gitInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    using( var proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process() )
    {
        proc.StartInfo = gitInfo;
        proc.Start();

        var output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        var error = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

        var logRaw = string.IsNullOrEmpty( output ) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty( error )
            ? error.Split( '\n' ).ToArray()
            : output.Split( '\n' ).ToArray();

        proc.WaitForExit();
        proc.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. The first one is to set the configuration for your git repo (or globally) to use the git askpass witch is "git config core.askpass git-gui--askpass". Call this as the first command for your process. The drawback here is that each time you do a modifying command it will ask for password.

Or you can have your own executable witch will ask for password once, and have the option to store the password into your application. But here you will have to be careful since if you don't store it properly it will be a security risk.